# Dropbox installation stuck with permission

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, dropbox

I tried to install Dropbox on my PC running Archlinux and I followed the command at Dropbox webpage.

The first command is ok, but when I tried the second command, it gives me the error:

> Couldn't start Dropbox.
>   This is usually because of a permissions error. Storing your home folder on a network share can also cause an error.
>
> Get more help at https://www.dropbox.com/c/help/permissions_error
>
> Please contact Dropbox support with the following info for help:
>
> /tmp/dropbox_errordHVSQm.txt

[image: Here is dropbox_errordHVSQm.txt]

I have tried to do it with `sudo` but it gave the same error.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you're simply missing `libxslt`. You should be able to just `pacman -S libxslt` and run the installation again.

Comment: Thanks, but I have installed it (tried your command but terminal gave (1/1) reinstalling libxslt  )

Comment: Ah, I see. You already had `libxslt` installed. You may need to add it to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LDFLAGS` environment variables.

Comment: How can I do that @Sly? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Try `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -lxslt"` before the command that you ran to set it temporarily. If that doesn't work, try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running the commands from the dropbox webpage?

**You are way better of using the installation instructions from the arch linux wiki:**
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dropbox#Installation